# Php: Form returns form

Tags: php, forms

I have a radio button form that returns a certain type of form for each particular option. The data that i get from the second from will be used to search in a database.
 My problem is that if i use the post method for both forms when i submit data in the second from i get the notice that i haven't done the same for the first one because my code verifies if the variables are empty each time the page is loaded. What can i do in PHP so the server will differentiate between the forms and won't do the checking each time data is submitted through post? I tried naming the submit buttons but it didn't seem to work.
The code that searches in the database it is written in another file and it is working.
Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$optiuneErr="";
$optiune="";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

   if (empty($_POST["optiune"]))
     {$optiuneErr= "Selectati optiunea";}
   else
     {$optiune = test_input($_POST["optiune"]);}
}
?>
<?php
$numeErr=$anErr=$regiuneErr=$succesorErr=$predecesorErr="";
$nume=$an=$regiune=$succesor=$predecesor="";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

    if (empty($_POST["nume"]))
     {$numeErr= "Introduceti numele";}
   else
     {$nume = test_input($_POST["nume"]);}
     if (empty($_POST["an"]))
     {$anErr = "Introduceti anul";}
   else
     {$an = test_input($_POST["an"]);}
     if (empty($_POST["regiune"]))
     {$regiuneErr = "Introduceti regiunea";}
   else
     {$regiune = test_input($_POST["regiune"]);}
     if (empty($_POST["succesor"]))
     {$succesorErr = "Introduceti succesorul";}
   else
     {$succesor = test_input($_POST["succesor"]);}
     if (empty($_POST["predecesor"]))
     {$predecesorErr = "Introduceti predecesorul";}
   else
     {$predecesor = test_input($_POST["predecesor"]);}
}
function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}
?>
<p><span class="error">* Selectati un camp.</span></p>
<form method="post" > 
<input type="radio" name="optiune" value="1" />Cauta dupa nume <br />
<input type="radio" name="optiune" value="2" />Cauta dupa an<br />
<input type="radio" name="optiune" value="3" />Cauta dupa regiune<br />
<input type="radio" name="optiune" value="4" />Cauta dupa succesor<br />
<input type="radio" name="optiune" value="5" />Cauta dupa predecesor<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Alege" />
<span class="error"> <?php echo $optiuneErr;?></span>
</form>

<?php
switch($optiune)
{
    case 1:
        echo '
        <p><span class="error">* Introduceti o valoare.</span></p>
        <form method="POST">
        Nume: <input type="text" name="nume"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Cauta" />
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $numeErr;?></span>
        </form>';
        break;
    case 2:
        echo '
        <p><span class="error">* Introduceti o valoare.</span></p>
        <form method="POST" >
        An: <input type="text" name="an"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Cauta" />
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $anErr;?></span>
        </form>';
        break;
    case 3:
        echo '
        <p><span class="error">* Introduceti o valoare.</span></p>
        <form method="POST">
        Regiune: <input type="text" name="regiune"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Cauta" />
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $regiuneErr;?></span>
        </form>';
        break;
    case 4:
        echo '
        <p><span class="error">* Introduceti o valoare.</span></p>
        <form method="POST">
        Succesor: <input type="text" name="succesor"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Cauta" />
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $succesorErr;?></span>
        </form>';
        break;
    case 5:
        echo '
        <p><span class="error">* Introduceti o valoare.</span></p>
        <form method="POST">
        Predecesor: <input type="text" name="predecesor"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Cauta" />
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $predecesorErr;?></span>
        </form>';
        break;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of isset() function.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit1']))
{

if (empty($_POST["optiune"]))
 {$optiuneErr= "Selectati optiunea";}
else
 {
    if(isset($_PoST['nume']))
    {
       $nume = test_input($_POST["nume"]);
    }
    else if($_POST['an'])
    {
      ///////some checking code/////
    }

    ////and so on for all individual forms///
  }
}
```

like this for the second form.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working. The problem is that I don't receive the notice that the second form needs to be filled when I submit it without any data.

Comment: have made some changes, take a look